# Pandas: save rows unique to one category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many categories with items in lists like so:

```
colors = ['green', 'red']
animals = ['cat', 'dog']
```

I have a large dataframe that has all items in the categories like so:

```
largedf = pd.DataFrame({'arow': ['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4'], 'green': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 'red': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 
                   'cat': ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a'], 'dog': ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a']})
    arow    cat dog     green   red
0   row1    b   b       b       a
1   row2    a   a       b       b
2   row3    b   b       b       b
3   row4    a   a       a       a
```

I want to save only the rows where `a` is the value for a certain category and only that category. `row3` would not be saved because it has `b` for all items,  `row4` would not be saved because it has `a` for all items.

`row1` would be saved because it has an `a` for `red` (even though there is a `b` for green, at least one `a` is in that category).

`row2` would be saved because there is at least one `a` in `cat/dog` (in this case, an `a` in both).

For each saved row, I'd like a column listing the category that has `a` and the percentage of `a` in that category (see output below).

```
shorterdf = pd.DataFrame({'arow': ['row1', 'row2'], 'green': ['a', 'b'], 'red': ['a', 'b'], 'cat': ['b', 'a'], 'dog': ['b', 'a']})
    arow    cat dog     green   red  category   percent
0   row1    b   b       b       a    colors     0.5
1   row2    a   a       b       b    animals    1
```

Comment: Once again: the wide vs long dataframe problem. Simply melt with your list values as indicators adjacent to value columns and then aggregate as needed. Keep data long and life will be easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a handy dictionary for renaming the existing dataframe's columns

```
m = {k: (v, k) for k, v in {
        **dict.fromkeys(colors, 'colors'),
        **dict.fromkeys(animals, 'animals')
    }.items()}

largedf[
    largedf.drop('arow', 1)
           .rename(columns=m.get)
           .eq('a').any(axis=1, level=0).sum(1).eq(1)
]

   arow cat dog green red
0  row1   b   b     a   a
1  row2   a   a     b   b
```

---

### Details

```
df = largedf.drop('arow', 1).rename(columns=m.get)
df

  animals     colors    
      cat dog  green red
0       b   b      a   a
1       a   a      b   b
2       b   b      b   b
3       a   a      a   a
```

---

```
df.eq('a')

  animals        colors       
      cat    dog  green    red
0   False  False   True   True
1    True   True  False  False
2   False  False  False  False
3    True   True   True   True
```

---

```
df.eq('a').any(axis=1, level=0)

   animals  colors
0    False    True
1     True   False
2    False   False
3     True    True
```

---

```
df.eq('a').any(axis=1, level=0).sum(1).eq(1)

0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Two questions: 1) How do I get the columns with the category and percentages? I tried combining this answer with part of Wen's solution, but can't get it to work. 2) How do I add a second argument to df.eq('a')? For example if I wanted it to count both `a` and `c`. Aside from that, this is easier for me and I appreciate the breakdown of steps!

Comment: It would be better to accept an answer and ask a new question.

Comment: Could you tell me how to add a second category to `df.eq('a')`? If I wanted to count both `a` and `c` within a category?  `df.eq('a'|'c')` doesn't work. I'll ask another question for the percentages/category columns.

Answer (score 2):

We using nunique to filter out the row we need

```
t=largedf[largedf.iloc[:,1:].nunique(1).gt(1)]

t=t.set_index('arow')
s=t.copy()
```

Then we change the columns to the category by using `map`

```
s.columns=s.columns.map(dict(zip(s.columns,np.repeat(['animals','color'],2))).get)

# get the percentage and the category accordingly 
s1=(s.eq('a').groupby(level=0,axis=1).sum()/2).stack()
# concat together 
pd.concat([t,s1[s1!=0].reset_index(level=1)],axis=1).rename(columns={'level_1':'category',0:'percent'})
Out[287]: 
     cat dog green red category  percent
arow                                    
row1   b   b     a   a    color      1.0
row2   a   a     b   b  animals      1.0
```

Comment: Could you explain a couple things a little more? What positions should `largedf.iloc[:,1:].nunique(1).gt(1)` give? Specifically, what does `iloc[:,1:]` represent? I'm getting an error `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nunique'`, but I see that there is a `nunique` for dataframes in the documentation.

Comment: iloc[:,1:] will not get the first columns , since that is irrelevant @Liquidity